# Set the same height of the div as other div has

Tags: html, css

How can I set the height of the `div` to be the same than another `div` with only CSS with text?

For example I have a div whose `max-width` is 10px and it contains the text

- CSS is one of the most famous Programming Language to design webpages

and have another div whose `max-width` is also 10px.

```
<div style="max-width:10px">CSS is one of the most famous Programming Language to design webpages</div>
<div style="max-width:10px"></div>
```

What I want is set the height of the second div equal to the height of the First Div relative to the content. If the div has more or less text it is adjustable by it.

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p38hmoz0/

---

**NOTE:** I can't use jquery or javascript for this purpose because it would be difficult for me to add it in the polymer as it uses shadow dom.**

Comment: @Daniel Pinzon Do you have answer to my question

Comment: working on that .... OP  `divs` aside or just one below another?

Comment: Then isn't possible with just CSS

Comment: @Daniel Pinzon I know this can be done by using javascript or jquery but it isn't possible for me to use it because it doesn't provide the accurate results and also i have to make many changes to add it to shadow dom. Is there anything in css which can do this

Comment: ***IF*** you want to avoid wrappers and can adjust your design to have the second div as a child of the first div then there's a css only way.

Comment: @Arbel I can make second div as a child of first div but how can then i will be able to do it by height:100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you can make the second `div` as a child of first `div`:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/p38hmoz0/6/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    CSS is one of the most famous Programming Languages to design webpages
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.parent {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 10px;
}
div.parent > div {
    max-width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #0ff; /* for demo purposes */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with css only if you can add a wrapper and use `display: table;`: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p38hmoz0/1/)

Note: I adjusted the max-width and added a blue background to the empty div to show the example.

HTML

```
<div class="table">
    <div style="max-width:100px">CSS is one of the most famous Programming Language to design webpages</div>
    <div style="max-width:100px" id="two"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
        display: table;        
}
.table div {
        display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: I was working  with `table-cell` too but as you see in the comments OP doesn't want the divs aside

Comment: I want div One Below Another

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it the way you explain as CSS is stateless, you cannot know anything that you didn't previously defined.
I suggest you to use a wrapper and table display

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="div1" style="max-width:10px">CSS is one of the most famous Programming Language to design webpages</div>
<div id="div2" style="max-width:10px"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper
{
    display: table;
}
#div1
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: table-cell;
}

#div2
{
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p38hmoz0/3/)